# Table only shows one value, when it should show many

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

I have a CRUD Project.

For this I made a Database in MySQL using OOP method, also with HTML, PHP, Bootstrap and CSS.

In this Database there are 3 tables: Customers, Orders and Products, for my question it's only needed Customers and Orders.

The problem I'm having is in Read Customers (file), when there are more than 1 regist, only the first appear, and I can't find out why.

If someone can help I would appreciate :)

Code

```
<?php

$id_customer = '';

if (isset($_GET["id_customer"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_customer"]))) {
    require_once "../connectDB.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers 
            INNER JOIN Orders
            ON Customers.id_customer = Orders.id_customer
            WHERE Customers.id_customer = ?";

    $columns = [
        "ID Cliente" => "id_customer",
        "Nome" => "fn_customer",
        "Apelido" => "ln_customer",
        "Email" => "email_customer",
        "ID Compra" => "id_order",
        "Data" =>"order_dt",
        "Total" => "order_total"
    ];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id_customer"]);

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result(); ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach (array_keys($columns) as $heading) { ?>
                                <th scope="col"><?= $heading ?></th>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php

                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>
                    <?php foreach (array_values($columns) as $column) { ?>
                        <td><?= $row[$column] ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
            <?php 
            }
        }
    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
        
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

I tried removing and changing some lines of the code, not much, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looping through your results. You want to wrap your foreach with one that goes through all the results:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
     <tr>
        <?php foreach (array_values($columns) as $column) { ?>
            <td><?= $row[$column] ?></td>
         <?php } ?>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ah, I was just going to say that. Don't forget the `<tr>` and `</tr>` table row tags.

Comment: Yea, just didn't know where to put them since I don't really understand the layout OP's trying to achieve

Comment: Inside the `while` loop and outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: makes sense, also fixed the code to close the while loop